# osX and html5 not compatible

Tags: macos, html

I have created a sample hello world code using html5 and trying to run it on firefox,chrome and safari on the osX. I do not see the output but rather see the the entire html code when i try to view it on the screen. The same code seems to be working fine on a ubuntu machine. I have checked the compatibility of my current browser too and they seem to be compatible.

here is the code I am using

```
 <!DOCTYPEhtml>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>
        Jamie was here.
    </p>
</body>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Choose "View source" in the browser. Do you see the same content? Does the file have .html ending?

Comment: Try <!DOCTYPE html> and at the bottom you must close the <html> tag like this </html>

Comment: @Juhana well I was using textEdit to create the html files, though I was saving them as.html files, the browser read them as text files with "apple seperated spacing between them" this seemed to have caused the issue. I downloaded a free text editor and the problem is solved for now.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a space between DOCTYPE and html, like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: A faulty doctype would not cause the browser to not render the HTML at all.

Answer (score -1):

Your first line is bogus.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>
        Jamie was here.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, this isn't really HTML5-specific HTML but simply pure HTML.